Do any Vaishnavite sects worship Dattatreya?
I see some claims at HSE that Dattatreya is not an Avatara of the Trimurti (Brahma, Vishnu and Siva) but is exclusively a Vishnu Avatara.
AFAIK, he is not the supreme deity of any major Vaishnavee sect - how prevalent is his worship among Vaishnavites?
Are there any Vaishnavite temples to Dattatreya where he is either the Moola Devata or a Parivara Devata?
